# Fancybox 2: overlay disappears when popup is called by click() method (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox-2

I want to ask an issue that I am having about opening a fancybox popup calling it from JQuery that I want to show automatically, so, this is what I do in Jquery:

```
document.getElementById('link-fancybox-popup').click();
```

I am just simulating a click in a link (`<a>`) that opens it. It works but the fancybox overlay (black background behind the popup) disappears and the popup is shown without that overlay.

It is very weird because if I delete that sentence that I wrote, when I click manually the popup, it works perfectly and the overlay is shown as well.

Anyone has had this behaviour ? Thank you.

Comment: You need to wrap your code inside the `.ready()` method. Here is your issue : http://jsfiddle.net/6n32gv8x/ and here it is fixed http://jsfiddle.net/6n32gv8x/1/

Comment: I did it in a JS file added to the HTML and it already had .ready() method inside BUT my problem was that in the HTML, I loaded that file BEFORE the fancybox libraries. So I changed the order of that files and it works perfectly like jsfiddle you sent me. Thank you @JFK !

Answer (score 1):

Normally I do not use any plugin for popup you can use following script to use overlay.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.clickme').click(function(){
        $('.popup,.mask').fadeIn();
    });
    $('.mask').click(function(){
        $('.popup,.mask').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

```css
.clickme{
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:10px;
    background:#00cfff;
    color:#fff;
}
.mask{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    z-index:2;
    display:none;
}
.popup{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#d30043;
    z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='outer'>
    <span class='clickme'>Click Me</span>
    <div class='mask'></div>
    <div class='popup'>I am a Popup</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really good, Mohammed. I am just helping with a plugin because I thought that it will be easier to handle it but with very few code you can do a great popup. Thank you for share and I will accept your answer if finally I can not find any extra solutions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<p>To display a lightbox click <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a></p>
        <div id="light" class="white_content">This is the lightbox content. <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.black_overlay{
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0%;
            left: 0%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            z-index:1001;
            -moz-opacity: 0.8;
            opacity:.80;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        }
        .white_content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 25%;
            left: 25%;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            padding: 16px;
            border: 16px solid orange;
            background-color: white;
            z-index:1002;
            overflow: auto;
        }
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/anujsoft/yrze23uv/)